# Exercise 7, Section 6.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space over the field of complex numbers. Prove that $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $T$ is annihilated by some polynomial over $\Bbb{C}$ which has distinct roots.

This problem is bit vague for me. Is “polynomial over $\Bbb{C}$ which has distinct roots” means polynomial of form $(x-c_1)\cdots (x-c_k)$, where $c_1,…,c_k\in \Bbb{C}$ are distinct?

**Proof:** $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $T$ is diagonalizable. Let $m$ be minimal polynomial of $T$. By theorem 6 section 6.4, $m=(x-c_1)\cdots (x-c_k)$, where $c_1,…,c_k\in \Bbb{C}$ are distinct. $(\Leftarrow)$ Conversely, suppose $\exists f\in F[x]$ such that $f=(x-c_1)\cdots (x-c_k)$, where $c_1,…,c_k\in \Bbb{C}$ are distinct and $f(T)=0$. Then $m|f$. So $m= (x-c_1)^{e_1}\cdots (x-c_k)^{e_k}$; $0\leq e_i\leq 1$. By theorem 6 section 6.4, $T$ is diagonalizable.

In proof, we didn’t use any property of $\Bbb{C}$. So this problem holds in field $F$. **Am I right?**

Comment: We can't know without knowing whether the proof of Theorem 6, Section 6.4, requires $F= \Bbb C$.

Comment: @RobertShore $T$ is diagonalizable$\iff$Minimal polynomial is of form $(x-c_1)\cdots (x-c_k)$, where $c_1,…,c_k\in F$ are distinct. $F=\Bbb{C}$ is a special case.

Comment: In this statement the field of complex numbers can be replaced by the field $F$ in which all roots of the characteristic polynomial of the linear operator lie.

Comment: @kabenyuk one of the benefit of working with field $\Bbb{C}$ is that every polynomial in $\Bbb{C}[x]$ “splits” (i.e. can be written as product of linear monic polynomial in $\Bbb{C}$). So we don’t have any irreducible factor. When we talk about diagonalizable, it is important to know about underlying field on vector space $V$. Thus if $\exists$ eigenvalue (root of characteristic polynomial) which is not in underlying field, then $T$ is not diagonalizable over underlying field.

Comment: I'm glad you understand the advantage of the field of complex numbers over the unfortunate other fields, but note that my comment is about a field that may well replace the field of complex numbers when studying a particular operator.

Comment: @kabenyuk yess. More explicitly, if $(x-c_1)\cdots (x-c_k)$ where $c_i$ are distinct ($c_i$ could be in extension field) annihilates $T$, then minimal polynomial $m$ is $(x-c_{r_1})\cdots (x-c_{r_s})$ where $r_i$ are distinct & $r_i\in \{1,…,k\}$, because $m| (x-c_1)\cdots (x-c_k)$. Since roots of minimal and characteristic polynomial are same, and roots of characteristic polynomial lie in field $F$, we have $c_{r_i}\in F$. Thus $T$ is diagonalizable over $F$. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already pointed to an exercise that showed that in order for a linear operator to be diagonalisable, its minimal polynomial must split into linear factors. Over non algebraically closed fields, there exist (by definition) monic polynomials that do not split into linear factors; moreover any monic polynomial$~P$ over $F$ occurs as minimal polynomial of some $F$-linear operator (for instance multiplication by the companion matrix of$~P$). So over any non algebraically closed field$~K$ there exist $K$-linear operators that are not diagonalisable even though they are annihilated by a polynomial without multiple roots (just make sure a polynomial has a irreducible factor of degree${}>1$, and avoid multiple roots).